# Can't go to weight paint mode when in pose mode

Tags: weight-painting

I 1st select bones and then go to pose mode, and now I can't leave the bones at pose mode while go to weight paint mode. whatever object I select, there is no option for weight paint mode, there is only object mode, edit mode, and post mode, 3 options in the list. I can't select any object when in pose mode actually.

Comment: These are the 3 modes of the armature, meaning you have selected the armature but not a mesh object. You should try 2 things: first make sure you've parented your object to the armature (select the mesh object and in the modifiers make sure there's an armature modifier). Second, in the top header menu > Edit > disable Lock Object Modes, that will allow to both select a bone in Pose mode and your mesh object.

Comment: the lock object mode is disabled but still can't select object in pose mode.